# Author attribution issue

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pymongo, author

How do I append data from a pymongo database into a list reviews
 I currently have:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient().db_name.collection_name
reviews = []
with open(db) as f:
  for line in f:
    reviews.append(db.loads(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient().db_name.collection_name
reviews = []
reviews.extend(list(db.find()))
```

This will append data from the collection to reviews